# Nested associations for multiple accounts

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, model-associations

I am trying to associate various login methods with the same `User` model in `mongo`.

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: String
  isVerified: { default: false, type; Boolean }
  accounts: {
    ref: 'Account',
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
  }
})

const AccountSchema = new Schema({
  facebook: {
    ref: 'FacebookAccount',
    type: Schema.Types.?
  },
  local: {
    ref: 'LocalAccount',
    type: Schema.Types.?
  },
  twitter: {
    ref: 'TwitterAccount',
    type: Schema.Types.?
  },
})

const LocalAccount = new Schema({
  email: String,
  name: String,
  phone: String,
  password: String,
  _user: {
    ref: 'User',
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
  }
})
```

What I would like to get the data coming back to me looking like would be:

```
{
  _id: '12345789',
  email: 'turdFerguson@gmail.com',
  accounts: {
    facebook: { ... }
    local: { ... }
  }
}
```

I'm really unsure about these associations though hence `Schema.Types.?` on the individual accounts. Also unsure if I should be using *embedded* vs *object* reference and where is appropriate. I'm going in circles trying to get the associations to match up.

Comment: Why not use one collection for this? This seems like overkill.

Comment: @Mikey I'd never considered that actually. I guess it is a feasible idea. Search if a user exists and then depending on the login method used for authentication store the data in the corresponding _account_. I will look into this and see if it will work with what I'm trying to accomplish. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you keep it simple with embedded.

Here is a quick suggestion:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    isVerified: { 
        default: false, 
        type: Boolean 
    },
    accounts: {
        local: {
            email: String,
            name: String,
            phone: String,
            password: String
        },
        facebook: {
            // fields related to Facebook
        },
        twitter: {
            // fields related to Twitter
        }
    }
})
```

I removed `email` as it seems redundant to have it since you already have `accounts.local.email`

Comment: thanks for the advice so much easier and working like a charm!